# Extract nested Json info into a new column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following format, with info from Google Places:

```
      geometry                                                      place_id
0     {'location': {'lat': 19.41, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJ72ctQ0D_0YURyVYdfRzImGU
1     {'location': {'lat': 19.42, 'lng': -99.17},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJ11QtkkX_0YUR5EK4tQCqY3A
2     {'location': {'lat': 19.43, 'lng': -99.18},'viewport':{...}}  TEST ChIJBUve6UX_0YURCRM4GwUtwsc
3     {'location': {'lat': 19.44, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJQYvciNX90YURv1n4r_l0wvo
4     {'location': {'lat': 19.45, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJkZX8gz__0YURSxUrmMO6JLQ
```

What I want to do is, for each row in the dataframe, get its lat and lng vlaues and set them as new columns, so that the dataframe would look like this:

```
      lat      lng       geometry                                                      place_id
0     19.41    -99.16    {'location': {'lat': 19.41, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJ72ctQ0D_0YURyVYdfRzImGU
1     19.42    -99.17    {'location': {'lat': 19.42, 'lng': -99.17},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJ11QtkkX_0YUR5EK4tQCqY3A
2     19.43    -99.18    {'location': {'lat': 19.43, 'lng': -99.18},'viewport':{...}}  TEST ChIJBUve6UX_0YURCRM4GwUtwsc
3     19.44    -99.16    {'location': {'lat': 19.44, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJQYvciNX90YURv1n4r_l0wvo
4     19.45    -99.16    {'location': {'lat': 19.45, 'lng': -99.16},'viewport':{...}}  ChIJkZX8gz__0YURSxUrmMO6JLQ
```

Not sure how to do this...
I've tried weird stuff like df['latitude'] = df[['geometry']]['location']['lat'], but this just doesn't work. I'm sure there must be an elegant solution I'm not familiar with...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your way to extract data from JSON file.

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(jsonfile, record_path=['location'],  meta=['place_id'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(jsonfile)

pd.merge(df1, df2 on='place_id')
```

Comment: Well, that does it. Thanks!